# Jquery mobile animations

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page with a form and some buttons.
I have a review button on the page. On the click of this button, I disable all the fields and show some new buttons, but the page is same.
Here is the link

```html
<a href="#" id="reviewBtn" data-inline="true" data-role="button"
                    onclick="disableFields()" data-transition="slide" data-icon="forward">Review</a>
```

I want the user to get a feeling that he has transitioned to a new page with all the fields disabled.

Is there a way to get show some animation like  `slideup` , on the  `onclick`  so that the user gets a feeling that he has transitioned to a new page?

Answer (score 0):

Using css animations or jquery animations would help you. something like below code would work.

```
  disableFields(){
       $('pageId').hide('fast');
       $('pageId').show('fast');
  }
```

Comment: I tried this. This does help but later on when I click on the next page. The current is not hidden and the new page is shown.. looks like this messes the jquery page transitions...

Comment: Instead of the anchor tag with href, we can change to input tag with type="button" and handle the page change using the [$.mobile.changePage()](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) in the button click handler function.